# How do I skip dependencies declared in project level Makefile while recursively building subdirectory?

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a C++ project managed by Make. The project-level Makefile has certain library paths defined as below.

```
LIBS = -lframework -lapp -lcore
```

I have another directory for a test app inside the project that does not use one of these dependencies (-lframework). How do I instruct project-level Makefile not to add these dependencies while recursing and building the sub directory?

Note: I ran `make -n` and observed that "-lframework" is added to the path while compiling the test directory although this is not specified in the test-level Makefile.

Comment: You'll have to provide more details.  Make does not _by default_ ever pass any make variables to sub-makes.  Are you really using recursive make?  Or are you in an environment with one invocation of make, that includes a lot of makefiles?  If you're in recursive make, what is the recipe that invokes the sub-make?  Does it pass the `LIBS` variable on the sub-make command line?  If so, that's your problem.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. After examining the Makefile in the test directory carefully, I found that LIBS variable was assigned as LIBS+= -lotherlib. This was the reason libs from project level were passed to subs.